# How to count string length of a domain list and group them by length?

Tags: php, arrays, string, count, string-length

I have a list of domain names, for example:

```
domain1.com
domain2.com
domainxxx2.com
dom.com
```

from that list I want to get:

```
length 7 [2]
length 10 [1]
length 3 [1]
```

I know how to split the tld and count each domain length, but dont know how to group and count those with the same length.

I would like to do it on PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quicker & cleaner but still untested

```
$sorted = array();
foreach($domains as $domain)
{
    $sorted[strlen($domain)][] = $domain;
}
```

Comment: Yes, definitely quicker than mine in terms of execution speed. :) When I described mine as "quick" I was referring to the amount of time I put into thinking of a solution.

Comment: Ya, that was clear.  Not sure why I prefaced my code like I did.

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty and untested:

```
$lengths = [];
for ($i = 1; $i <= 255; $i++) {
    foreach ($domains as $domain) {
        if (strlen($domain) === $i) {
            $lengths[$i][] = $domain;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use Pickle's answer instead. It's much faster.

Comment: Haven't used your code but it helped me to put this together: 

**[foreach($domains as $domain)
{
 $tmp = explode(".", $domain);
 
 $length = strlen(trim($tmp[0]));
 $count[$length] = $count[$length]+1;
}

print_r($count);]**